# Store object of a class within the class itself

Tags: c++

How do I store an object of a class within the class itself?

I know that I have to use the static keyword to accomplish what I want. Thus the class should look something like:

```
class my_class {
public:
    static my_class instance;
    my_class() {
        my_class::instance = this
    }
};
```

Below is the exact code as it appears in the class

```
namespace ArmISA {
    class ISA {
        protected:
            static ISA* isa;
            MiscReg miscRegs[NumMiscRegs];
            const IntRegIndex *intRegMap;
            .....
        public:
            ISA() {
                ISA::isa = this;
                ...
            }
        ...
    };
}
```

The error I get is:

> error: could not convert 'ArmISA::ISA::isa' from 'ArmISA::ISA*' to 'ArmISA::ISA'

Comment: the error is not caused by the presented code

Comment: I see, very well, I will try to dig deeper into what the cause might be.

However, it seems to compile when I use
`static ISA isa; ISA::isa = *this;`

Does this give any insight as to what the problem might be?

Could it be some form of incomplete declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_class::instance = *this;` will work, but I hope that you are aware that every time you create a new instance of the class, your `instance` member will be overwritten. Additionally, this means that `instance` is a copy of `*this` and not a reference - changes to one are invisible to the other.

Another option is to declare `instance` as a pointer, in which case both pointers refer to the same object and then `instance = this;` would compile:

```
static my_class* instance;
```

However, I am not sure what exactly you try to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a pointer. Use `my_class::instance = *this`.

Comment: It works..but could you explain why the following doesn't?
class my_class {
public:
    static my_class *instance;
    my_class() {
        my_class::instance = this;
    }
};

Comment: If the question was directed at me, I'm modifying existing open-source C++ code and trying to obtain reference to an object that I know is created only once

Comment: No, I'm sorry about that. I just missed writing the semicolon in my comment. It does exist in the source file

Comment: `class my_class { public: static my_class *instance; my_class() { my_class::instance = this; } };` is perfectly fine. I don't know why it does not compile with your compiler.

Comment: I'm not sure either..maybe this has something to do with inheritance at my end. I'm modifying existing open-source code and that may be a reason.
However, `my_class::instance = *this` works

Comment: are you sure it works? this is not a reference to `this`, it is a copy of it, which is detached from that moment on.

Comment: That is a valid point.
Basically, there is a class that stores all the registers of an architecture.
Sadly, I'm not too familiar with C++ namespaces and classes and am thus trying to save the object as static so that I am able to reference it easily in the future..

However, I don't think this meets my requirement as I expect the changes to that object to reflect in my static 'variable' as well.
But doing `my_class::instance = *this` will only give me a copy by value which will start to diverge as updates are made to `this`

Comment: Then make `instance` a pointer, as I noted in my answer. However, if you don't prevent public access to the class constructor, you can't prevent overwriting the `instance`

Comment: I only which the one who downvoted the answer would explain in which way `my_class::instance = *this` does not prevent the error concerning  conversion of my_class* to my_class&&.

Answer (score 0):

To initialize a static member variable of non-integral type (or, in C++11, non-`constexpr`), do that outside the class.

For example:

```
struct Foo
{
    static Foo bar;
    double x_;
    Foo( double x ): x_( x ) {}
};

// Preferably in an implementation file:
Foo Foo::bar( 3.14 );
```

The declaration outside the class is always formally the *definition*, which provides storage for the variable (needed if you ever take the address).

---

If you want to provide a header-file only module, one alternative is to provide access to the static variable via a function, like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    static Foo& bar()
    {
        static Foo theBar( 3.14 );
        return theBar;
    }

    double x_;
    Foo( double x ): x_( x ) {}
};
```

Another technique is to inherit from a class template that provides the static variable.

Comment: The first blurb of code is subject to the static initialization order fiasco, prefer the second blurb.

Comment: MooingDuck: maybe SO pings you for any activity on question you have commented on?

Comment: From what I've read, SO detects that there's only two users in a thread, and special-cases that as far as pings go.  So I probably got pinged since it couldn't think of anyone else that comment could be directed to.